# Make a custom user field searchable and sortable in administrator list

Tags: administrator, isis-template

I'm trying to figure how to make a custom user field searchable, and sortable, in admin users panel.

My custom field stores a client ID. As I can have multiple accounts per ID, i'd like to make this custom field searchable, and sortable.

I can't find any documentation, all I can find is frontend oriented content, can someone explain how does administrator search bar works, how to index fields, and maybe custom fields ?

Code to display a custom user field in admin panel (users list):

```
<tbody>
<?php
    //to get fields by name
    function getValueByFieldName($customFields, $field_name) {
        foreach ($customFields as $field) {
            if ($field->name == $field_name){
                return $field->value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
?>
<?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) :
    $canEdit   = $this->canDo->get('core.edit');
    $canChange = $loggeduser->authorise('core.edit.state',  'com_users');
    $customFields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_users.user', JFactory::getUser($item->id), true); 
    $field_name_value = getValueByFieldName($customFields, 'field_name');
    
    // If this group is super admin and this user is not super admin, $canEdit is false
    if ((!$loggeduser->authorise('core.admin')) && JAccess::check($item->id, 'core.admin'))
    {
        $canEdit   = false;
        $canChange = false;
    }
?>
    <tr class="row<?php echo $i % 2; ?>">
        <td class="center">
            <?php if ($canEdit || $canChange) : ?>
                <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.id', $i, $item->id); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <?php echo $custom_field_value; ?>
            
        </td>
```

Comment: Thanks for asking in JSE. Please take our [tour] while you wait for feedback/support.

Comment: I don't believe you will be able to make them searchable very easily as the custom fields are stored in the com_fields component table(s) while the core User fields are in the com_user tables. I would think you would need a very modified Model in com_user to combine the data from the various tables so that it can be searched. I am not sure that you can override or extend the core com_user Models. Sorting would also require changes tot he default com_user Model.

Comment: maybe the simpliest solution is to modifying the filter_search bar query ?